# How to set Y axis values to the left only and not on both left and right side using MPAndroidChart BarChart

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mpandroidchart

I have figured out how to set the X axis values to display at the bottom and not at the top using the method below. The issue I have now is that my Y axis values display on both left and right and I only want them to display on left side of the chart.

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
   // Reload data source
   Items = new ArrayList<>();
   Items.clear();
   Items.addAll(response.body());
   //currentReportingGroup = Items.get(0).ReportingGroup;
   //ItemsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: ");
   //load(view);
   BarChart chart = (BarChart) aq.id(R.id.chart).getView();
   XAxis xAxisChart = chart.getXAxis();
   YAxis yAxisChart = chart.getAxisLeft();
   //yAxisChart.setValueFormatter(new MyAxisValueFormatter());
  // yAxisChart.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.);
   xAxisChart.setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
   BarData data = new BarData(getXAxisValues(), getDataSet());
   chart.setData(data);
   chart.setDescription("");
   chart.animateXY(2000, 2000);
   chart.invalidate();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the right axis using:

```
chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```